# Adding HTML content to angular material $mdDialog

Tags: html, angularjs, modal-dialog, material-design, angular-material

I have written the following piece of code to display some contents in angular material dialog box. it works fine when i add plain text to ***textContent*** . when i add HTML its displays HTML as text. how do i bind HTML to ***textContent***

**This Works**

```
  <a href="#" ng-click="$scope.Modal()">Sample Link</a>

  $scope.Modal = function () {
      $mdDialog.show(
          $mdDialog.alert()
              .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('body')))
              .clickOutsideToClose(true)
              .textContent('sample text')
              .ok('Ok')
      );      
  }
```

**This Doesn't Works**

```
  <a href="#" ng-click="$scope.Modal()">Sample Link</a>

  $scope.Modal = function () {
      $mdDialog.show(
          $mdDialog.alert()
              .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('body')))
              .clickOutsideToClose(true)
              .textContent('<div class="test"><p>Sample text</p></div>')
              .ok('Ok')
      );
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You need to append to the template,

```
 $mdDialog.show({
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      template: '<md-dialog md-theme="mytheme">' +
        '  <md-dialog-content>' +
        '<div class="test"><p>Sample text</p></div>' +
        '        <md-button ng-click="closeDialog();">Close</md-button>' +
        '  </md-dialog-content>' +
        '</md-dialog>',
      locals: {

      },
      controller: DialogController
    });
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZCHFaE?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3):

You can add html in template and just add variable in displayOption. This will work.

Template Code

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="confirm-dialog-answer.html">
<md-dialog aria-label="confirm-dialog">
    <form>
        <md-dialog-content>
            <div>
                <h2 class="md-title">{{displayOption.title}}</h2>
                <p>{{displayOption.content}} <img src="{{displayOption.fruitimg}}"/></p>
                <p>{{displayOption.comment}}</p>
            </div>
        </md-dialog-content>
        <div class="md-actions" layout="row">
            <a class="md-primary-color dialog-action-btn" ng-click="cancel()">
                {{displayOption.cancel}}
            </a>
            <a class="md-primary-color dialog-action-btn" ng-click="ok()">
                {{displayOption.ok}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </form>
</md-dialog>
</script>
```

Controller Code

```
$mdDialog.show({
                      controller: 'DialogController',
                      templateUrl: 'confirm-dialog-answer.html',
                      locals: {
                       displayOption: {
                        title: "OOPS !!",
                        content: "You have given correct answer. You earned "+$scope.lastattemptEarnCount,
                        comment : "Note:- "+$scope.comment,
                        fruitimg : "img/fruit/"+$scope.fruitname+".png",
                        ok: "Ok"
                       }
                      }
                     }).then(function () {
                        alert('Ok clicked');

                     });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use template instead of textContent, textContent is used for show plan text in a model. It does not render HTML code

```
$mdDialog.show({
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.msg = msg ? msg : 'Loading...';
                },
                template: 'div class="test"><p>{{msg}}</p></div>',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose: false,
                fullscreen: false
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlContent instead of textContent to render HTML. Heres an excerpt from the documentation available at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#mddialog-alert

> $mdDialogPreset#htmlContent(string) - Sets the alert message as HTML.
>   Requires ngSanitize module to be loaded. HTML is not run through
>   Angular's compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit counter intuitive to use a template when you only need to inject one or two things in.  To avoid using a template, you need to include 'ngSanitize' for it to work.

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngSanitize'])
.controller('btnTest',function($mdDialog,$scope){
  var someHTML = "<font>This is a test</font>";
    $scope.showConfirm = function(ev) {
      // Appending dialog to document.body to cover sidenav in docs app
      var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
        .title('Please confirm the following')
        .htmlContent(someHTML)
        .ariaLabel('Lucky day')
        .targetEvent(ev)
        .ok('Please do it!')
        .cancel('Sounds like a scam');
      //Switch between .htmlContent and .textContent. You will see htmlContent doesn't display dialogbox, textContent does.         
      $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
        $scope.status = 'Saving Data';
      }, 
      function() {
        $scope.status = 'You decided to keep your debt.';
      });
    };

})
```

Notice the injected HTML:

```
var someHTML = "<font>This is a test</font>";
```

I found this example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJLeOL?editors=1010#0).

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Angular Material Design API has predefined function for add HTML content to the alert dialog:

```
an $mdDialogPreset with the chainable configuration methods:

$mdDialogPreset#title(string) - Sets the alert title.
$mdDialogPreset#textContent(string) - Sets the alert message.
$mdDialogPreset#htmlContent(string) - Sets the alert message as HTML. Requires ngSanitize module to be loaded. HTML is not run through Angular's compiler.
$mdDialogPreset#ok(string) - Sets the alert "Okay" button text.
$mdDialogPreset#theme(string) - Sets the theme of the alert dialog.
$mdDialogPreset#targetEvent(DOMClickEvent=) - A click's event object. When passed in as an option, the location of the click will be used as the starting point for the opening animation of the the dialog.
```

The link to the documentation: [Angular MD API](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)